# Изменение стилей с помощью JS у нескольких элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть скрипт, который меняет положение бегунка с помощью css стилей. Когда бегунок один все работает хорошо. Но стоить их размножить - начинаются проблемы. Как исправить ситуацию?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('input[name=size]:checked', '.product__size-control').val());
  });

  $('.product__size-control-input').on('click', function(){
    let value = Number.parseInt(this.value);
    let currentElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
    let currentLabel = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-label');

    console.log(value);

    switch(value){
      case 1: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(0%)'); 
      break;
      case 2: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(100%)');
      break;
      case 3: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(200%)');
      break;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f5;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #babfd0;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.product__size-control-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color .2s ease-out;
}

.product__size-control-label:hover {
  color: #373535;
}

.product__size-control-label:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.product__size-control-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.product__size-control-input:checked + .product__size-control-label {
  color: #373535;
}

/*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
input {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector" style="width: 33.3333%; transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_3"name="size" value="1" checked="">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_3"
  for="size_20_3">35&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_2" name="size" value="2">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_2"
  for="size_20_2">30&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_1"name="size" value="3">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_1"
  for="size_20_1">25&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не использовать id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых проблема в label-ах и радио-кнопках... `for="size_20_3"` и похожее, при дублировании подменил на `for="size_21_3"` и заработало:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('input[name=size]:checked', '.product__size-control').val());
  });

  $('.product__size-control-input').on('click', function(){
    let value = Number.parseInt(this.value);
    let currentElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
    let currentLabel = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-label');

    console.log(value);

    switch(value){
      case 1: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(0%)'); 
      break;
      case 2: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(100%)');
      break;
      case 3: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(200%)');
      break;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f5;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #babfd0;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.product__size-control-label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color .2s ease-out;
}

.product__size-control-label:hover {
  color: #373535;
}

.product__size-control-label:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.product__size-control-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.product__size-control-input:checked + .product__size-control-label {
  color: #373535;
}

/*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
input {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector" style="width: 33.3333%; transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_3"name="size" value="1" checked="">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_3"
  for="size_20_3">35&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_2" name="size" value="2">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_2"
  for="size_20_2">30&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_1"name="size" value="3">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_1"
  for="size_20_1">25&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector" style="width: 33.3333%; transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_21_3"name="size" value="1" checked="">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_3"
  for="size_21_3">35&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_21_2" name="size" value="2">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_2"
  for="size_21_2">30&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">
    <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_21_1"name="size" value="3">
    <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_1"
  for="size_21_1">25&nbsp;см</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Во-вторых, раз уж используется JS, можно вообще отказаться от лейбелов, а при клике добавлять новый класс на кликнутый элемент, в котором будут записаны другие стили. При этом, смотрите, насколько упрощается код (в первую очередь HTML) Иногда легче дописать пару строчек JS, чем делать супер-сложные фокусы на CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product__size-control-item').on('click', function(){
    var i = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').index( $(this) );
    //Среди найденных классов у родителя кликнутого... находим индекс кликнутого элемента.
    console.clear(); console.log(i);
    
    var selector = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
    selector.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 100 * i + '%');
    // 100 * 0 == 0, 100 * 1 == 100, 100 * 2 == 200 ... и можно без case.
    
    $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); // сюда дописать стили...
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f5;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #babfd0;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
  list-style: none;
  width: 33.33333%;  
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color .2s ease-out;
}


.product__size-control-label:hover {
  color: #373535;
}



.product__size-control-input:checked + .product__size-control-label {
  color: #373535;
}

/*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
input {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">35&nbsp;см</div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">30&nbsp;см</div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">25&nbsp;см</div>
</div>

<div class="product__size-control">
  <div class="product__size-control-selector"></div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">35&nbsp;см</div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">30&nbsp;см</div>
  <div class="product__size-control-item">25&nbsp;см</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё работает корректно, если не забывать что нужно прописывать в каждой копии свои значения для id и for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#show').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('input[name=size]:checked', '.product__size-control').val());
   });

   $('.product__size-control-input').on('click', function(){
    let value = Number.parseInt(this.value);
    let currentElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.product__size-control-selector');
    let currentLabel = $(this).parent().find('.product__size-control-label');

    console.log(value);

    switch(value){
     case 1: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(0%)'); 
     break;
     case 2: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(100%)');
     break;
     case 3: currentElement.css('transform', 'translateX(200%)');
     break;
    }

   });
  });
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #878686;
}

::-ms-clear, ::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}

.product__size-control {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1f2f5;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #babfd0;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.product__size-control-item {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.33333%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.product__size-control-label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(55, 53, 53, .7);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Dodo Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color .2s ease-out;
}

.product__size-control-label:hover {
    color: #373535;
}

.product__size-control-label:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.product__size-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.product__size-control-input:checked + .product__size-control-label {
    color: #373535;
}

/*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
input {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__size-control">
 <div class="product__size-control-selector" style="width: 33.3333%; transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_3"name="size" value="1" checked="">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_3"
  for="size_20_3">35&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_2" name="size" value="2">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_2"
  for="size_20_2">30&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_1"name="size" value="3">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_1"
  for="size_20_1">25&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="product__size-control">
 <div class="product__size-control-selector" style="width: 33.3333%; transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_6"name="size" value="1" checked="">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_3"
  for="size_20_6">35&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_7" name="size" value="2">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_2"
  for="size_20_7">30&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
 <div class="product__size-control-item">
  <input type="radio" class="product__size-control-input" id="size_20_8"name="size" value="3">
  <label class="product__size-control-label" data-testid="menu__pizza_size_1"
  for="size_20_8">25&nbsp;см</label>
 </div>
</div>
```